# Regex in R: remove multiple URLs from string

Tags: r, regex

I would like to remove multiple web URLs from a string. If the string is the following:

`this is a URL http://test.com and another one http://test.com/hi and this one http://www.test.com/`

It should return

`this is a URL and another one and this one`

I tried using the following code:

`gsub(" ?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[.|/](.*)", "", string)`

But it returns me this:

`this is a URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will also work, instead of `(.*)` we can use `[^\\.]*` (till the dot of the domain) and `\\S*` to match till the end of the url (until a space is found):

```
gsub("\\s?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)([^\\.]*)[\\.|/](\\S*)", "", string)
# [1] "this is a URL and another one and this one"
```

Answer (score 1):

`.*` will match until the end of string without constraint, so all parts after the first url are removed, normally urls don't contain white space, you can use `\\S`(match none white space) instead of `.`(match any character) to avoid the problem:

```
gsub(" ?(f|ht)(tp)s?(://)(\\S*)[./](\\S*)", "", string)
# [1] "this is a URL and another one and this one"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following *regex / code* :

```
gsub("https?:\\/\\/(.*?|\\/)(?=\\s|$)\\s?", "", string)
# [1] "this is a URL and another one and this one"
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rgrhW9/2)**